# Routing wifi from laptop to pc via ethernet issues

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ip, routing

So I was routing my internet from laptop to pc via ethernet due to issues with my network card and I mistakenly changed the ip settings on the adaptors on both devices and now I can't get the bridged connection to work.

Does anyone know what the settings are supposed to be for this to work. Are the IP, subnet and DNS to be static or automatically assigned. Both devices running Windows 10 I believe.